# Ad hoc Shapes with extended Model Orchard CMS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, razor, orchardcms, shapes, orchardcms-1.7

My goal is to add the full register shape in a modal.

To achieve this, I add my content in my layout:

```
WorkContext.Layout.ModalFirst.Add(New.Register(), "15");
```

My register view looks nice with bootstrap modal.

Everything seems to work.

BUT

I use the contrib.Profile and itWorks.ExtendedRegistration in order to display adding field in profile and in registration.

These fields doesn't show up.

I debug and put some breakpoints into controller that display register. But no one fire up.
So my conclusion is that the Ad Hoc shape directly inject the cshtml.

My question is:

How to add into the Shape the Model.UserProfile that is needed to display added fields ?

```
@using (Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost()) { 
<fieldset>
    <legend>@T("Account Information")</legend>
    <div>
        <label for="username">@T("Username:")</label>
        @Html.TextBox("username") 
        @Html.ValidationMessage("username") 
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">@T("Email:")</label>
        @Html.TextBox("email") 
        @Html.ValidationMessage("email") 
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password">@T("Password:")</label>
        @Html.Password("password") 
        @Html.ValidationMessage("password") 
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="confirmPassword">@T("Confirm password:")</label>
        @Html.Password("confirmPassword") 
        @Html.ValidationMessage("confirmPassword") 
    </div>
        @if (Model.UserProfile != null)
        {
            <br />
            <fieldset>
                <legend>@WorkContext.CurrentSite.SiteName</legend>
            @Display(Model.UserProfile)
                </fieldset>
        }
    <div>
        <button class="primaryAction" type="submit">@T("Register")</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
}
```

Edit:

My problem comes only from the fact that I dynamically loads the shape.

If I type url to directly called the shape : http://DomainName.com/Users/Account/Register
my added fields are displayed.

If I use the Shape Ad Hoc : WorkContext.Layout.ModalFirst.Add(New.Register(), "15");

It's launch the same shape (same cshtml) but my added fields are not displayed.

I know why, it's simply don't pass into the controller that injects the UserProfile into the shape:

```
var shape = _orchardServices.New.Register();

        var user = _orchardServices.ContentManager.New("User");
        if (user != null)
        {
            shape.UserProfile = _contentManager.BuildEditor(user);
        }

        return new ShapeResult(this, shape);
```

So the question is How to do these lines further into the layout view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the way to use same lines in my cshtml:

```
var orchardServices = WorkContext.Resolve<IOrchardServices>();
var contentManager = WorkContext.Resolve<IContentManager>();

var shape = orchardServices.New.Register();

var user = orchardServices.ContentManager.New("User");
if (user != null)
{
    shape.UserProfile = contentManager.BuildEditor(user);
}

WorkContext.Layout.ModalFirst.Add(shape, "15");
```

And in my Register.cshtml on my own module that extends Orchard.User I have these lines:

```
@if (Model.UserProfile != null)
{
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    @Display(Model.UserProfile)
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
}
```

And now everything is working :)

Answer (score 0):

This might help : [Extra fields doesn't get data (SOLVED)](http://extendedregistration.codeplex.com/discussions/358692)

Comment: Hello, it doesn't help me. In my case, I load the correct register.cshtml from my own module. I load the Model.UserProfile. But my problem is that it is empty. I look for a way to redo the injection in the shape like the controller for [an Ad hoc template](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/06/30/creating-shapes-on-the-fly.aspx): `shape.UserProfile = _contentManager.BuildEditor(user);`

Comment: there are other with the same problem. Without posting all your code and how you wire things up, that seems the best asnwer. Check this one too: http://extendedregistration.codeplex.com/discussions/260237

Comment: Have you created the new fields in your Profile Part? How do you do that? In code? Have you added it (ProfilePart) to your User ContentType?

Comment: I created my field into the Profile Part, simply in content definition - Content Part - edit Profile - add new Field (type input), not in code, yes the profile part is on the User ContentType (load by Contrib.Profile module): `ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("User",
                cfg => cfg
                    .WithPart("ProfilePart")
                );`

Comment: If I load the form from url (see edition of my question), all works. It's only missing something in the called of shape: `WorkContext.Layout.ModalFirst.Add(New.Register(), "15");`